# Unable to delete S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Created a bucket and happen to add zero kb file.

1. Tried to delete that object. Got success message but object was not deleted.
2. Created another 10kb size file with same name and uploaded it in S3, thinking it will overwrite the original zero kb file. Ended up with both versions in S3. Unable to delete both.
3. Then tried enabling and disabling versioning and deleting files. Ended up with nothing in  bucket but both file as previous version.
4. Created Expiration, and delete expired version policy but that didn't work either.

Current state:

- Bucket versioning: Disabled
- Bucket objects with 'Hide Version" = None
- Bucket objects with 'Show Version" = two

  - file 0 Kb (Delete marker): Version = null
  - file 10 KB: Version = not null (has some version number)

Unable to delete both using console or CLI.

Problem: Can't delete bucket till both objects in older versions are deleted.

How to address this?

Comment: once you've enabled versioning it cannot be disabled.
you would need to create another bucket.
First create a new one, then move the files you want to keep, and then delete the one that has versioning.

Comment: You can delete object versions using the management console. When you select "Show Version", it will display all versions of the object. You can then select (tick) the versions and choose Actions/Delete. If this does delete the objects, please tell us more about what happened (any error messages?).